# How to change the partition size of a running Debian Linux machine?

Tags: linux, filesystems, debian, partition, disk-usage

I have a dedicated server (Debian 8) with two 1.8T SSD drives running as RAID 1. In the default configuration only a small portion of the disc space is used, I would like to modify partitions to use everything.

Output of lsblk:

```
$ lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk  
|-sda1            8:1    0    4G  0 part  
| `-md1           9:1    0    4G  0 raid1 /
|-sda2            8:2    0    2G  0 part  [SWAP]
`-sda3            8:3    0  1.8T  0 part  
  `-md3           9:3    0  1.8T  0 raid1 
    |-vg00-usr  253:0    0    5G  0 lvm   /usr
    |-vg00-var  253:1    0    5G  0 lvm   /var
    `-vg00-home 253:2    0    5G  0 lvm   /home
sdb               8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk  
|-sdb1            8:17   0    4G  0 part  
| `-md1           9:1    0    4G  0 raid1 /
|-sdb2            8:18   0    2G  0 part  [SWAP]
`-sdb3            8:19   0  1.8T  0 part  
  `-md3           9:3    0  1.8T  0 raid1 
    |-vg00-usr  253:0    0    5G  0 lvm   /usr
    |-vg00-var  253:1    0    5G  0 lvm   /var
    `-vg00-home 253:2    0    5G  0 lvm   /home
```

Output of df:

```
$ df
Filesystem            1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1                4095616  283056   3812560   7% /
udev                      10240       0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs                   3287176   98888   3188288   4% /run
/dev/dm-0               5029504 1344456   3406520  29% /usr
tmpfs                   8217932       4   8217928   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                   8217932       0   8217932   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                    8217932       0   8217932   0% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg00-var    5029504  573944   4177032  13% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-home   5029504 3001552   1749424  64% /home
tmpfs                   1643588       0   1643588   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                   1643588       0   1643588   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                   1643588       0   1643588   0% /run/user/1001
```

How can I create a /data with the rest of the free space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've got LVM and appear from what you've shown have a fair bit of unused space in your volume group you should be able to just use lvcreate to add another volume and mount it at /data. You can confirm how much is available in vg00 by using vgdisplay as root. Anyway this should work:

```
lvcreate -L50G -n data vg00
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/vg00-data #or some other fs type if you prefer
```

And then add a line to /etc/fstab for the new partition. Probably by UUID is best.

One thing to note, in the above command I started out only assigning 50G to the new volume, in my experience it's much better to do that than immediately fill up the volume group. It's much simpler to safely grow a volume (even with it online) than shrink one. Usual caveats apply about backing up data appropriately before touching it though of course. You can resize a volume using this process:

```
lvextend -L+50G /dev/mapper/vg00-data # make it 50G larger
reseize2fs /dev/mapper/vg00-data # assuming extfs
```

On remote connections I'd recommend issuing those commands inside screen/tmux so that if your ssh session drops they don't run the risk of a mysterious death halfway through.

Answer (score -1):

I think your requirements contradict each other - if you are **not** an expert in this area, then touching a **running** system sounds like a **bad** idea.

Anyway, there are various tools (like resize2fs, or even gparted) that you can look into; which seem to work for [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime).

Then, one recommendation: before trying any of that on your running server, you better create a virtual machine with a matching configuration (probably smaller disks) to *test* any change on that VM prior applying it to your real system!